# How to add a component programmatically in Angular.Dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, shadow-dom

I would like to dynamically build a component tree basing on some information received from AJAX calls.

How to programmatically add a component to the DOM from inside of other component? I have `<outer-comp>` and I would like, basing on some logic, insert an `<inner-comp>`. The following code just inserts the elements `<inner-comp></inner-comp>` to the DOM, and not actual `<inner-comp>` representation.

```dart
@NgComponent(
  selector: 'outer-comp',
  templateUrl: 'view/outer_component.html',
  cssUrl: 'view/outer_component.css',
  publishAs: 'outer'
)
class AppComponent extends NgShadowRootAware {      
  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    DivElement inner = shadowRoot.querySelector("#inner");
    inner.appendHtml("<inner-comp></inner-comp>");
  }
}
```

**Update:**
I managed to render the inner component correctly in the following way, but I'm still not sure if this is the proper way:

```dart
class AppComponent extends NgShadowRootAware {
  Compiler compiler;
  Injector injector;
  AppComponent(this.compiler, this.injector);

  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    DivElement inner = shadowRoot.querySelector("#inner");
    inner.appendHtml("<inner-comp></inner-comp>");    
    BlockFactory template = compiler(inner.nodes);
    var block = template(injector);
    inner.replaceWith(block.elements[0]); 
  }
```

}

Comment: could you show how you call your AppComponent constructor? how do you create a new compiler and a new injector?

Comment: @0xor1 no need to call the constructor - that's what dependency injection is for ;-)

Comment: so how would you achieve this in code that was not in a NgComponent class? say in the main method you wanted to call `document.body.appendHtml('<my-comp></my-comp>')` how would you then get angular to compile that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would be a proper use of the block API.

```dart
class AppComponent extends NgShadowRootAware {
  Compiler compiler;
  Injector injector;
  Scope scope;
  DirectiveMap directives;

  AppComponent(this.compiler, this.injector, this.scope, this.directives);

  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    DivElement inner = shadowRoot.querySelector("#inner");
    inner.appendHtml("<inner-comp></inner-comp>");    
    BlockFactory template = compiler([inner], directives);
    Scope childScope = scope.$new();
    Injector childInjector = 
        injector.createChild(new Module()..value(Scope, childScope));
    template(childInjector, [inner]);
  }
}
```

Also, if you ever need to recompile the inner template make sure you do `childScope.$destroy()` on the previous `childScope`.

Comment: Thank you for the very fast response, your solution works fine.

Comment: @pavelgi: This code works fine in angular 0.9.4. But in angular 0.9.6, compiler(...) require second parameter (DirectiveMap directives). What is DirectiveMap and what should I pass  into the function?

Comment: @pavelgj: Could you, please, update your response to match with the changes introduced in angular 0.9.9?

Comment: how do you new up the arguments to the AppComponent constructor?

Comment: You just declare any arguments you need - the dependency injection mechanism takes care of supplying proper values for you.

Answer (score 10):

The API has changed in AngularDart 0.9.9:

- BlockFactory now is ViewFactory
- scope.$new now seems to be scope.createChild(scope.context)
- injector.createChild(modules) now requires a list of modules (instead of a single one)

AngularDart 0.10.0 introduces these changes:

- NgShadowRootAware not is ShadowRootAware
- ..value() now is ..bind(., toValue: .)

So the code of pavelgj now looks like so:

```auto
class AppComponent extends ShadowRootAware {
  Compiler compiler;
  Injector injector;
  Scope scope;
  DirectiveMap directives;

  AppComponent(this.compiler, this.injector, this.scope, this.directives);

  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    DivElement inner = shadowRoot.querySelector("#inner");
    inner.appendHtml("<inner-comp></inner-comp>");    
    ViewFactory template = compiler([inner], directives);
    Scope childScope = scope.createChild(scope.context);
    Injector childInjector = 
        injector.createChild([new Module()..bind(Scope, toValue: childScope)]);
    template(childInjector, [inner]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you accidentally just copy-paste @pavelgj answer.

Comment: Ouch! You're right. Hope I managed to fix the code - seems I've got rid of my tested version again. In any case, `ng-include` does something similar, so it's always a good idea to have a look at the implementation of `NgIncludeDirective`.

Comment: What about ng-repeat? 

When I tried to append something like "<inner-comp ng-repeat='rows in ctrl.list'></inner-comp>" the NgRepeat directive didn't work. Even the constructor of NgRepeat wouldn't be called. After a while I began to suspect it's not my fault. 

What do you think, should ng-repeat work, or is there an important initialization missing in Pavel's example?

Answer (score 3):

The above code samples on longer work because of changes in the Angular Dart library. Specifically ViewFactory.call which no longer takes an injector but takes a Scope and a DirectiveInjector.   I've tried adapting what's above and I get very close. The component shows up but none of the bindings are replaced (I see {{cmp.value}} for example.

Here's the code I'm using. I think the issue here is that DirectiveInjector is coming in as null.

```dart
void main() {
  IBMModule module = new IBMModule();
  AngularModule angularModule = new AngularModule();

  Injector injector = applicationFactory()
  .addModule(module)
  .run();

  AppComponent appComponent = injector.get(AppComponent);
  appComponent.addElement("<brazos-input-string label='test'/>");
}

@Injectable()
class AppComponent {
  NodeValidator validator;
  Compiler _compiler;
  DirectiveInjector _injector;
  DirectiveMap _directiveMap;
  NodeTreeSanitizer _nodeTreeSanitizer;
  Scope _scope;

  AppComponent(this._injector, this._compiler, this._directiveMap, this._scope, this._nodeTreeSanitizer) {
    validator = new NodeValidatorBuilder.common()
                      ..allowCustomElement("BRAZOS-INPUT-STRING")
                      ..allowHtml5()
                      ..allowTemplating();
  }

  void addElement(String elementHTML) {
    DivElement container = querySelector("#container");
    DivElement inner = new DivElement();
    inner.setInnerHtml(elementHTML, validator: validator);
    ViewFactory viewFactory = _compiler.call([inner], _directiveMap);
    Scope childScope = _scope.createChild(new PrototypeMap(_scope.context));
    if (_injector == null) {
      print("injector is null");
    }
    View newView = viewFactory.call(childScope, _injector);
    container.append(inner);
    newView.nodes.forEach((node) => inner.append(node));
  }
}


class IBMModule extends Module {
  IBMModule() {
    bind(BrazosInputStringComponent);
    bind(BrazosTextAreaComponent);
    bind(BrazosButtonComponent);
    bind(ProcessDataProvider, toImplementation: ActivitiDataProvider);
    bind(AppComponent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did finally get this to work but was not happy with having to add a timer:

```dart
@Injectable()
class AppComponent{
  NodeValidator validator;
  Compiler _compiler;
  DirectiveInjector _directiveInjector;
  DirectiveMap _directiveMap;
  NodeTreeSanitizer _nodeTreeSanitizer;
  Injector _appInjector;
  Scope _scope;

  AppComponent(this._directiveInjector, this._compiler, this._directiveMap, this._nodeTreeSanitizer, this._appInjector, this._scope) {
    validator = new MyValidator();
  }

  void addElement(String id, String elementHTML) {
    DivElement container = querySelector(id);
    DivElement inner = new DivElement();
    container.append(inner);
    Element element = new Element.html(elementHTML, validator: validator);
    ViewFactory viewFactory = _compiler.call([element], _directiveMap);
    if (_scope != null) {
      Scope childScope = _scope.createProtoChild();
      View newView = viewFactory.call(childScope, _directiveInjector);
      newView.nodes.forEach((node) => inner.append(node));
      Timer.run(() => childScope.apply());
    } else {
      print("scope is null");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `new Future(() => childScope.apply());` would be a slightly better way or `scheduleMicroTask(() => childScope.apply());` (might not work though).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I believe the correct way would be to schedule it as a microtask. Why do you think this would not work though?

Comment: ScheduleMicrotask might execute it too early.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

The package http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_angular contains this decorator/directive as `bwu-safe-html`

**------**

I use a custom directive for that

```dart
@NgDirective(
  selector: '[my-bind-html]'
)
class MyBindHtmlDirective {
  static dom.NodeValidator validator;

  dom.Element _element;
  Compiler _compiler;
  Injector _injector;
  DirectiveMap _directiveMap;

  MyBindHtmlDirective(this._element, this._injector, this._compiler, this._directiveMap) {
    validator = new dom.NodeValidatorBuilder.common()
        ..allowHtml5()
        ..allowImages();
  }

  @NgOneWay('my-bind-html')
  set value(value) {
    if(value == null) {
      _element.nodes.clear();
      return;
    }
    _element.setInnerHtml((value == null ? '' : value.toString()),
                                             validator: validator);
    if(value != null) {
      _compiler(_element.childNodes, _directiveMap)(_injector, _element.childNodes);
    }
  }
}
```

It can be used like

```dart
my-bind-html='ctrl.somehtml'
```

**Angular issue**
I created an issue to include this functionality into Angulars `ng-bind-html` https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/742 (declined)

Comment: The issue is closed. This functionality will not be added to Angular for security reasons.