# angular dart >> Best way to create a table:column renderer

Tags: dart, angular-ui, angular-dart

I'm hopping this awesome community can steer me on the right direction. I came from the flash/flex/js world, and I like how simple it is to define an item renderer in flex. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have an Angular component which consist of a form and a html table. I have the columns, headers, rows, etc. all populating correctly using ng-repeat. I want to be able to define column "renderers", so if someone passes me a column property like "renderAs: 'button'" or "renderAs: 'progress'" I should be able to render the entire column as a button, or progress bar, etc.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. ng-bind-html="getColRenderer(column.renderAs, column.value)" which
   returns HTML based on 'renderAs'. As you all probably know, this
   will only work with basic HTML stuff, but I cannot append an
   'ng-click', or an 'href' due to angular's security. So, I opted
   for something else.
2. I semi-have a good solution embedding a "ng-switch" inside my
   ng-repeat. I had an ng-if but with several types of potential
   "renderers" I opted for the switch. This somehow seems like future
   problems while trying to display too many columns or rows, just my
   fears.
3. Decorators - I like decorators, but it seemed a bit too much for
   something as a simple button that calls something on click or a
   progress bar with 2 values. So, I halted going into this path, but
   if this is the shinning path all walk, then by all means.

I hope someone out there has ran/done something like this and can steer me on the right course of action. If the ng-switch or ng-if is okay, then I'm good to go.

Once again, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Instead of `ng-bind-html` you could use something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/26763491/217408. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871982. I haven't used any of this since a while.

Comment: Thank you, but no, I'm not using ng-bind-html anymore. I'm using an ng-switch, and this gives me a bunch of tags for all unused cases:  
`<td class="ng-binding" ng-switch="c.id" style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; width: 100px;" ng-repeat="c in columns" angu-table="">

    <!--

    ANCHOR: [ng-switch-when]=passed_count

    -->
    <!--

    ANCHOR: [ng-switch-when]=blocked_count

    -->
    <!--

    ANCHOR: [ng-switch-default]=

    -->
    <span class="ng-binding" ng-switch-default="" angu-table=""></span>

</td>`  I want to get rid off those empty ANCHORs...or use something else.