# setInnerHtml doesn't evaluate Mustache

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I add some HTML content adding setInnerHtml() inside my NgComponent.

Logging shows, that directives are instantiated but `{{ctrl.xxx}}` expressions are not evaluated.

For setting the HTML I use a directive derived form [ng-bind-html](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/79b7525a790ce73a50c2874e2f43110fbce61d16/lib/directive/ng_bind_html.dart) with a custom `NodeValidator` and the following `value` method.

```dart
  set value(value) {
    _element.setInnerHtml((value == null ? '' : value.toString()),
                                             validator: validator);
    _log.finest(value);
    if(value != null) {
      BlockFactory template = _compiler(_element.children, _directiveMap);
      Block block = template.bind(_injector)(_scope);
    }
  }
```

I have also some `<input type='text' ng-model='ctrl.someValue'>` in the inserted HTML.
The debugger shows that the ng-model is instantiated and
the getter `ctrl.someValue` gets called
but the input element doesn't show the returned value.

When I insert the generated HTML statically as `template` all works fine.

How can get dynamically inserted HTML fully processed by Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

The package http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_angular contains this decorator/directive as `bwu-safe-html`

**------**

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui/blob/c71f8b8a30279d87e5a7e3008bbcdb4895123077/lib/modal/modal.dart#L203)

```dart
  @NgOneWay('ac-bind-html')
  set value(value) {
    if(value == null) {
      _element.nodes.clear();
      return;
    }
    _element.setInnerHtml((value == null ? '' : value.toString()),
                                             validator: validator);
    _log.finest(value);
    if(value != null) {
      _compiler(_element.childNodes, _directiveMap)(_injector, _element.childNodes);
    }
  }
```

see also my answer on [How to add a component programatically in Angular.Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423565) for the full code