# Add "unknown" component from List en AngularDart

Tags: dart, components, angular-dart

I have a list of differents components in controller and I need render them, How?

Dart:

```dart
@NgController(
selector: '[my-controller]',
publishAs: 'ctrl'

)
class MyController {

  List components;

  MyController() {
     components = new List();
     components.add(new ComponentType1());
     components.add(new ComponentType2());
  }
}
```

HTML:

```dart
<div my-controller>
  <div ng-repeat="component in ctrl.components">
     <!-- How render the component here? -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a component programatically in Angular.Dart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423565/how-to-add-a-component-programatically-in-angular-dart)

Comment: Could you expand on your use-case?  Looking at your code here, the best way is simply to enumerate all the components in the HTML.

Comment: I have a few components that extends a parent components.

User is a parent component and I have student and teacher components that extends of user.

I add teachers and students to the list, and I need render this list.

I implemented "toString" to create HTML tags but this create new components, not render the actuals.