# Include HTML inside ng-repeat list

Tags: html, dart, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-dart

I am writing a list using ng-repeat as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="string in MyCtrl.strings">
  {{ string }}
</div>
```

Now, the above code, treat the HTML within the string as plain text.

I have modified it as follows:

```dart
<div ng-repeat="string in MyCtrl.strings">
  <div ng-include="string"></div>
</div>
```

But i am getting an error on the console and the div is not showing up any text.
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) "

How do i include HTML inside ng-repeat list.

Comment: You can take a look an my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423565

Comment: I get error on the line template(childInjector, [inner]);" saying only one argument expected.

Comment: There was a breaking change in one of the previous Angular updates. It shouldn't be to hard to find out which one can be omitted. I haven't time just yet to take a close look. Please add another comment if you can't figure it out.