# How to display a string with new lines as a string with <br />'s in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Given that I have a string being displayed on the page in AngularDart.

```
... <strong>Notes: </strong> {{cmp.selectedStudent.notes}} ...
```

How can I make it display multi-line? In the string I have newline characters, I want them to be encoded as `<br />` characters in the html output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the `'\n'` in your string with `<br/>` and use something like the proposed `my-bind-html` directive shown in my answer here [How to add a component programatically in Angular.Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423565) (the code might be a bit outdated due to a lot of recent changes in Angular)

You could use `ng-repeat` and repeat over your notes lines but first you need to split them by `'\n'` so you get an array of lines.

```dart
List<String> _notesList = null; 
List<String> get notesList { 
  if (_notesList==null) _notesList = notes.split("\n").toList(); return _notesList; 
}
```

.

```dart
<span ng-repeat="note in cmp.selectedStudent.notesList">{{note}}<br /></span>
```

Comment: Ok thanks a List<String> is ok with ng-repeat.

  List<String> _notesList = null;
  List<String> get notesList {
      if (_notesList==null)
        _notesList = notes.split("\n").toList();
      
      return _notesList;
  }

<span ng-repeat="note in cmp.selectedStudent.notesList">{{note}}<br /></span>

Answer (score 1):

By default, angular doesn't interpret HTML balise to avoid some unpredictible behavior or others bad thing, but you can disable this verification with

> ng-bind-html

link to the official doc : [NgHtmlBind](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular-directive.NgBindHtml)

So you can replace directly the '\n' character by the 'br' html node.

So you can do :

```
// ...
String getHtmlBrNote() {
  return this.notes.replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
}
// ...
```

and after in angular

```
... <strong>Notes: </strong> <span ng-bind-html="cmp.selectedStudent.getHtmlBrNote()"></span> ...
```

And it will be ok

Comment: ng-bind-html was not ported to Dart and also is not planned to be ported due to security reasons. The link in my Answer shows the code to build your own port of the ng-bind-html directive.

Comment: I just see that in the AngularDart official doc [NgHtmlBind](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular-directive.NgBindHtml) and i have test my code in Dartium and it works. But maybe it's depreciated

Comment: Ok, I have to try that. It says it evaluates to a String, maybe it escapes all `<>&...`, but why would it need a NodeValidator for this.
Maybe this has changed with the availability of custom NodeValidator a few weeks ago.

Comment: I think it's because in the angular process, treatment of the NgHtmlBind is do after and if it doesn't a string, it can break the angular parser, or something like that. **but it's just a idea, i don't have check my self.**

Comment: Thanks for bringing it to my attention. There was a definitively a change since I last checked this directive. I will try it again, but probably not today.

Comment: Wouldn't this be unsafe for other characters other than \n?

Comment: I'm not a expert in web security, but if you ONLY DISPLAY information, it should be safe. For the choose of the solution, in my point of view it really depend of what you want to do. for just put a 'br', ng-repeat will be  perfect, but if you want apply a style that depend of the input, i think ng-bind-html will be fine.

Comment: As I understand, sometimes people put <script> tags into things like this with javascript embedded

Comment: Yes, it's why i have write "for display purpose only", if you just display information provide by your server, it will be fine, but if you send this information to your server, it will be bad, very bad