# Add divElement with ng-model programmatically

Tags: dom, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to build a rich text editor in angular dart, but I'm having some issues when I'm adding an element by code.

Html:

```
<div id="text-container" class="container"> </div>
```

Dart:

```
class RichTextEditorComp implements ShadowRootAware{

  String text = 'Write <b>here</b><br>\n  <br> This is an <i> image</i> ';
  html.DivElement _textbox;
  html.DivElement _toolbar;
  html.DivElement _textEditorContainer;

  RichTextEditorComp(this._element){
    _textEditorContainer = new html.DivElement();
    _textEditorContainer.children.add(_buildToolbar());
    _textEditorContainer.children.add(_buildEditor(text));
  }

  final html.Element _element;

  void onShadowRoot(final html.ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
    this._container =  _element.querySelector('#text-container');
    this._container.children.add(_textEditorContainer) ;
  }


  _buildEditor(String startingPointText) {
    _textbox = new html.DivElement();
    _textbox.setAttribute('ng-model', 'text');
    _textbox.contentEditable = "true";
    return _textbox;
  }
```

When I compile to js, the ng-model does not work. I guess I need to do some more, but I can't find out what to do. I've tried this html as well:

```
<div id="text-container" class="container" ng-model="text" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

And this works as planned. How to sort this out?

Comment: There are few similar questions here about this topic. You need to "compile" the DOM node to make Angular evaluate tag names and attributes but the commands changed since I used it the last time myself. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423565)

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to avoid dynamically adding elements in the first place. Consider this solution.

**rich_text.html**

```
<div>
    <div id="toolbar">...</div>
    <div id="textbox" ng-model="text" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

**Dart**

```
@Component(selector: '.container', templateUrl: 'rich_text.html')
class RichTextEditorComp {
  String text = 'Write <b>here</b><br>\n  <br> This is an <i> image</i> ';
}
```

This will have your models binding appropriately, while being much simpler and being idiomatic angular.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This solves the problem but does not answer my question. I know you are right, but I'd like to sort out the problem dynamically for the learning purpose